# OneDrive to trigger an Azure Function upon file sync

Tags: azure, triggers, onedrive

Azure and OneDrive friends,

I have the following usecase and need your help! Imagine there is an organization with Office 365 accounts and more specifically - the users utilize OneDrive, synchronized to local folders. We have a separate system running on an Azure environment. Is there a possible way whenever a file from any of the users is created / edited / synced in their local drives and respectively uploaded to the OneDrive... drive to trigger an Azure Function that lives in the Azure Environment from above?

Is there a way to set such triggers for all users (~150) from within an admin account?

Regards,
Borislav Nanovski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but I´d use a Logic App with the OneDrive connector in Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-onedrive

Comment: Thank you for your answer! And can I use one instance of Logic App with many OneDrive instances (i.e. to link all users' OneDrives)?

Comment: I think you need one logic app per user since the OneDrive connector only accepts one account. You could reduce work time by exporting the template of one working logic app and deploying all the others using this one. In the parameters section, you can add the users' OneDrive account programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Jesus Hernandez. Use a Logic App that has a OneDrive trigger.
[image: OneDrive Logic App trigger options]